# (React) How to update input field based on dynamically typed other fields’ calculation results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this problem, banging my head to the wall for the last several days, where I have a simple form, there might be more than one divs with four inputs but they are all related to each other. What I'm trying to do is to calculate the last input's in a div value which is based on the rest of the inputs' value and are typed dynamically and then to `setState()` to return a new state. I have handler functions (to add, remove or change value of input fields) which work when I don't need to handle this particular update. Now here's the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      bank: 10,
      totalPrice: 0,
      hands: [
          {
              name: "hand1",
              backPrice: 0,
              bankPrice: 0,
              commision: 0,
              realPrice: 0
          }
      ],
      handCount: 1
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const hands = this.state.hands;

    // initialized variables needed to calculate a result
    const totalPrice = hands.reduce((total, hand) => {
        return (hand.backPrice || 1) * total;
        }, 1);

    // lastHandPrice is ALWAYS needed, it is the base of the rest of calculations
    const lastHandPrice = (this.state.bank * totalPrice) /
        (hands[hands.length - 1].bankPrice -
        (hands[hands.length - 1].commision / 100));

    const newHands = hands.reduceRight(
        // calculation starts in reverse, with the first value being lastHandPrice
        // it returns an array of number values reversed again to be in correct order
        (newHands, hand, ind, array) => {
            let prevHand = array[ind + 1];
            let prevPrice = newHands[array.length - ind - 2];
            if (hand == array[array.length - 1]) {
                return newHands.concat(lastHandPrice)
            } else {
                return newHands.concat(
                    prevPrice * (1 - (prevHand.commision / 100)) /
                    (hand.bankPrice - (hand.commision / 100))
                )
            }
        }, []
    ).reverse();


    if (this.state.hands !== prevState.hands)
        this.setState({
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            hands: this.state.hands.map((hand, index) => {
                return Object.assign(hand, {realPrice: newHands[index]})
            })
        })
}
```

There are four main input fields in a div, represented in `state.hands`. 
So this code works just perfect in my terminal but react throws me a `Maximum update depth exceeded` error when I try the following:

- Add a new hand to the array
- Try to enter anything in the input

There's nothing more I can really do about it. I tried a few other methods to achieve this, but I always get the same error. It seems like some kind of loop starts to work but I just can't figure it out. Why it won't let me to update `state.hands`?

Input change/add/or remove handlers are very predictable, just updating the needed value, adding a div of four input fields, and removing the selected div. To change the value I `map()` over the `state.hands` and then `Object.assign()` the property value I need to the object I need (hand1, hand2, etc).

EDIT (the rest of the code):

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const handName = event.currentTarget.parentNode.getAttribute("name");
    const handInput = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("name");
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;
    if (handInput === "bank" || handInput === "totalPrice") {
        this.setState({
            [handInput]: value
        });
    } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            hands: prevState.hands.map(
            hand => {
                if (hand.name === handName) {
                    return Object.assign(hand, { [handInput]: value })
                } else {
                    return hand
                }
            }),
        }));
    }
}

handleAddHand = () => {
    const handCount = this.state.handCount;
    const name = `hand${handCount + 1}`;
    const hand = {
        name,
        backPrice: 0,
        bankPrice: 0,
        commision: 0,
        realPrice: 0
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        hands: prevState.hands.concat({...hand}),
        handCount: prevState.handCount + 1
        })
    );
}

handleRemoveHand = (event) => {
    const handName = event.currentTarget.parentNode.getAttribute("name");
    const handIndex = this.state.hands.findIndex(hand => 
        hand.name === handName);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        hands: [
            ...prevState.hands.slice(0, handIndex),
            ...prevState.hands.slice(handIndex + 1)
        ]
    }));
}
render() {
    const listHands = this.state.hands
        .map(hand =>
            <HandInputs
                key={hand.name}
                name={hand.name}
                backPrice={hand.backPrice}
                bankPrice={hand.bankPrice}
                commision={hand.commision}
                realPrice={hand.realPrice}
                handleChange={this.handleInputChange}
                removeHand={this.handleRemoveHand}
            />
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                name="bank"
                value={this.state.bank}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <input
                name="totalPrice"
                value={this.state.totalPrice}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            {listHands}
            <button onClick={this.handleAddHand}>Add Hand</button>
        </div>
    );
}


function HandInputs(props) {
    return (
        <div name={props.name}>
            <input type="text" value={props.backPrice}
              name="backPrice" onChange={props.handleChange} />
            <input type="text" value={props.bankPrice}
              name="bankPrice" onChange={props.handleChange} />
            <input type="text" value={props.commision}
              name="commision" onChange={props.handleChange} />
            <input type="text" value={props.realPrice}
              name="realPrice" onChange={props.handleChange} />
            {props.name !== "hand1" && 
              <button onClick={props.removeLeg}>Remove leg</button>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think that you are always getting to the `setState` part and then it's keep calling `componentDidUpdate` function. Can you add the rest of the code here for checking this? maybe you should call this function from the handlers instead of `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Edited the post with the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` it makes the component go over the update life cycle again and call `componentDidUpdate` in a loop.
Your check: `if (this.state.hands !== prevState.hands)` will always be `true` because you always create a new `hands` array in state:

```
this.setState({
   totalPrice: totalPrice,
   hands: this.state.hands.map((hand, index) => { <-- always cause a new array
      return Object.assign(hand, {realPrice: newHands[index]})
   })
})
```

One solution for this is to use the `callback` function as the second argument to `setState`. This callback will be called after the change of the state and inside it you can use the `state` as you used it in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
// the same function as your componentDidUpdate
afterStateChange = () => {
   const hands = this.state.hands;

   // initialized variables needed to calculate a result
   ...

   // you can call `setState` here (you don't need to check if the state is different from prevState
   this.setState({
       totalPrice: totalPrice,
       hands: this.state.hands.map((hand, index) => {
          return Object.assign(hand, { realPrice: newHands[index] });
       })
   });
```

And then for example you can use it here:

```
  handleAddHand = () => {
    const handCount = this.state.handCount;
    const name = `hand${handCount + 1}`;
    const hand = {
      name,
      backPrice: 0,
      bankPrice: 0,
      commision: 0,
      realPrice: 0
    };
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        hands: prevState.hands.concat({ ...hand }),
        handCount: prevState.handCount + 1
      }),
      this.afterStateChange <-- here
    );
  };
```